# Findstr regexes works fine when tested in cmd.exe and does not work as script

Tags: batch-file

I got disparate results for the same expression in command-line interface and in batch script. In command-line interface for the following line:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=()"  %x in ( 'Dir /b !destination! ^| FINDSTR /R /C:"AB1234[^-]"' ) do SET "Katalog=%x(%y)"
```

I got the expected result that is:

> "Katalog=AB1234(MNS00000123456789)"

for equivalent expression in batch script:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=()"  %%x in ( 'Dir /b !destination! ^| FINDSTR /R /C:"AB1234[^-]"' ) do SET "Katalog=%%x(%%y)"
```

the result is different:

> "Katalog=AB1234-2(Mnk1233210006789)"

I should say that I have two similar catalogs each one beginning with `AB1234`, the first one is `AB1234(MNS00000123456789)` and the second `AB1234-2(Mnk1233210006789`). I used the regex `[^-]` in hope of eliminating the second catalog but it does not work in script. Please help me in finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first expression also fails, but I doubt, that you tested really with the `!destination!` part on the command line.

The `!destination!` part creates the problem, as you use delayed expansion and delayed expansion will have it's own escape phase of carets independent of quotes, but only when at least one exclamation mark is in the line.

That's the cause why your caret in `[^-]` will be removed.

The solution is simple, double the caret.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=()"  %%x in ( 'Dir /b !destination! ^| FINDSTR /R /C:"AB1234[^^-]"' ) do SET "Katalog=%%x(%%y)
```

Or dont' use delayed expansion here

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=()"  %%x in ( 'Dir /b "%destination%" ^| FINDSTR /R /C:"AB1234[^-]"' ) do SET "Katalog=%%x(%%y)
```